# Limit of a Markov Chain?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stationary-processes

Consider a Markov Chain of state space $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$ with transition matrix $P$ as follows
 \begin{equation*}P=\left(
    \begin{array}{rrrr}
    0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\
    1/4 & 0 & 3/4 & 0 \\
    0 & 1/3 & 0 & 2/3 \\
    1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
    \end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}

If it exists, find $\lim_{n\to \infty} P^{n}$.

---

I've set up the balance equations and solved them with the mass equation to get 
the stationary distribution as $(0.2,\;\; 0.2,\;\; 0.3,\;\; 0.3)$ and am confused with how this helps me calculate the limit. I checked, for high powers of n what the matrix approaches and it seems to reach
 $$\left(
    \begin{array}{rrrr}
    0.4 & 0 & 0.6 & 0 \\
    0 & 0.4 & 0 & 0.6 \\
    0.4 & 0 & 0.6 & 0 \\
    0 & 0.4 & 0 & 0.6 \\
    \end{array}\right)
$$

So how am I supposed to use the limit/stationary law and $P$ to get to that matrix? I ask, even though I can evidently numerically solve for the limit but there are some other questions such as $P^{2n}$ and $P^{2n-1}$ that I also need to know.

Thanks

Comment: First of all, have you checked the reducibility and the periodicity of the matrix $P$?

Comment: It is irreducible and the periodicity is 2, but what does that have to do with the limit?

Comment: If it's irreducible but periodic ($d >1$), does $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} P^n$ exist?

Comment: For the high powers of $n$ that you checked, I wonder if you have checked both odd and even values of $n$ (which seems to relate to the final sentence in your question).

Comment: Yes I have checked both odd and even values and they both approach the same limit. I'm sorry thanasissdr but I'm not sure if I actually calculated the periodicity correctly, I just assumed that as every state had period of 2 then the matrix has period 2? Is that wrong?

Comment: Ok so I've found that the matrix does have a period of 2 and it does not approach that matrix as n goes to infinity, I misinterpreted the results. It alternates, with the same values but in different locations so obviously for P^(2n-1) and P^(2n) I can just calculate the matrix for high powers and see what it tends to, but to what end do I need to use the limit laws? Can I not just do this numerically with a calculator, or do I need some algebra to show it?

Comment: "Yes I have checked both odd and even values" Obviously, you only checked even values of $n$. Please take more seriously comments seeking to help you.

Comment: Did you read my last comment? I literally just stated that. Please take more seriously comments seeking to correct themselves.

Comment: What? Where did you "seek to correct" yourself? You only said, unequivocally, that "Yes [you] have checked both odd and even values", which, in retrospect, does not seem accurate. (Unrelated: Please use @, unless you do not want the user you address your comment at, to read it.)

Comment: In literally the comment before yours, I said that I misinterpreted the results and that I realized it has different values for even and odd powers. It was the most recent comment before yours, you might want to read the post of that which you are just trying to insult instead of help.